# Packet redirection to different IP address

Tags: security, networking, icmp, arp

I am currently working on a research project to analyze different attacks in a local network and I would like to find out if it is possible to perform a redirection attack on network layer 3 that is similar to an ARP spoofing or ICMP redirect attack.

Lets assume I have the following three hosts:

- H1 (IP=10.0.0.1,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:01)
- H2 (IP=10.0.0.2,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:02)
- H3 (IP=10.0.0.3,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:03)

If an echo request packet is sent from H1 to H2, with an ARP spoofing attack I can modify H2's ARP cache and make H2 send the echo reply to H3 for example. For that the host H2 will change the MAC address of the echo reply packet.

Now I would like to achieve something similar on network layer 3. So if H1 sends an echo request to H2, H2 should answer to a different IP address than the one of H1, for example to H3's IP, 10.0.0.3. Hereby an important precondition is that IP spoofing cannot be done, so H1 cannot send an echo request packet that has the src address set to 10.0.0.3, the src address of the request packet has to be the correct address of H1, 10.0.0.1

So I am curious if it is somehow possible, or if there is a network protocol that will change the IP address of a request packet and send the reply packet to a different IP address.

- So if H1 sends: Request (src=10.0.0.1, dst=10.0.0.2)
- Then H2 should send a reply to a different address like: Reply (src=10.0.0.2, dst=10.0.0.3)

Thank you a lot for your help!

Edit: The network I am using is a SDN network (Software Defined Network), so packets can be routed with either layer-2 or layer-3 addresses (or both). Therefore I would like to know if it is possible to also spoof IP addresses and not just MAC addresses.

Comment: To do something like this on a LAN (layer-2 network), you need to mess with the ARP cache. This is because LANs don't use layer-3 addresses. The reason for ARP is to resolve a layer-3 address to a layer-2 address so that it can be delivered on the LAN.

Comment: Ron, thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned that the environment is a SDN network (Software Defined Network). So packets can be routed either with layer-2 or layer-3 addresses, or both, depending on the flow rules. Therefore I am interested in spoofing IP addresses, not just MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can really do is put H1 on a different subnet, and set H3 as the default gateway for both subnets:

```
H1 (IP=10.1.0.1,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:01)
H2 (IP=10.0.0.2,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:02)
H3 (IP=10.0.0.3,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:03)
   (IP=10.1.0.255,MAC=00:00:00:00:00:04)
```

H3 is multi-homed.

An echo from `10.1.0.1` to `10.0.0.2` will then get its reply sent via `10.0.0.3`.

```
H1 (10.1.0.1) ⇾ (H2) 10.0.0.2
```

As `10.0.0.2` is not on the `10.1.0.0/24` subnet, the default gateway is looked up:

```
ARP: Who has 10.1.0.255?
H3: 10.1.0.255 is 00:00:00:00:00:04
00:00:00:00:00:01 ⇾ 00:00:00:00:00:04
```

Then H3 routes the packet onto the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet:

```
ARP: Who has 10.0.0.2?
H2: 10.0.0.2 is 00:00:00:00:00:02
00:00:00:00:00:03 ⇾ 00:00:00:00:00:02
```

H2 receives the packet and echos attempts to echo it back to H1 (`10.1.0.1`). As `10.1.0.1` is not on the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet, the packet is sent to the default gateway, `10.0.0.3`. As H2 has just received a the original packet from `10.0.0.3`, the ARP of `00:00:00:00:00:03` is still cached so the reply goes to H3, albeit with an IP destination of 10.1.0.1.

Comment: Hi SilverlightFox, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this still doesn't do what I am looking for. In the example I would like that H3 rewrites to IP address of the packet. So if 10.0.0.2 sends the echo reply to 10.0.1.0, routed through H3 at 10.0.0.3 as the default gateway, I need H3 to rewrite the original IP src from 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.3. Is that somehow possible? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, H3 could rewrite what it likes.

Comment: But how would you make H3 (assuming it is a host) rewrite the IP addresses of the packet? What you describe in your answer is similar like an ICMP redirection attack, but in that case the IP addresses of a packet are not rewritten?

Comment: I guess you are assuming that H3 is an infected host an acts as a man-in-the-middle that sniffs packets, rewrites them and sends them out. Correct? In my case I am looking for a legitimate way to make H3 rewrite the packets IP addresses.